# Is there any way to get data from a JSON file into an html file

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have an application that builds a course website. The application creates an X amount of JSON files which populate the html pages using javascript.

Lets say in my html file I have a line like

```
<title>CSE 308 Home</title>
```

But instead of CSE 308 being hard coded into the html file I want it to be a variable that reads from a json file.

So something like

```
<title> ./js/CourseDetails.json.titleName </title>
```

Comment: Look at some basic servlets and JSP pages for a start, learn about JSTL and maybe jquery

Comment: Why is this tagged `Java`? There is a difference.

Comment: You could create a REST API which returns JSON information for a particular page (Look into Spring Boot or Jersey). You can have this return relevant course information (either stored in a DB or in .json files) and map the content of the JSON using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you getting the data from a server, or locally?

Comment: I'm getting it Locally

@SiddharthNand 95% of my application is in java. I'm having trouble with the last 5%

Comment: Can I see your Java Code

Comment: It's 1000s of lines long and I doubt it would help the question. I wouldn't even know which section is pertinent

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a meaningful solution. There are countless ways this could be done depending on what you're using on the front and back ends. I'm not sure how this could be thousands of lines long and be totally static on the front end-a quick tutorial on Java web apps might be a more efficient approach in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

JSON File As This Stuff

```
data = '[{"name" : "Ashwin", "age" : "20"},{"name" : "Abhinandan", "age" : "20"}]';
```

Link JSON File:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

Do Something Like This:

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(`${mydata[i].name} ${mydata[i].age}`);
    item.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("list-container");
    element.appendChild(item);
}
```